# Print the shop name repeatedly using Selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, python-requests, webdriver

As it print all details but problem is that print Master Juice repeatedly as below is highlighted in picture  that is my link https://www.foodpanda.pk/restaurants/new?lat=24.9414896&lng=67.1676002&vertical=restaurants from where i scrape

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('F:/chromedriver')
driver.get("https://www.foodpanda.pk/restaurants/new?lat=24.9414896&lng=67.1676002&vertical=restaurants")


# response = scrapy.Selector(text=driver.page_source)
list = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("ul.vendor-list li")
length = len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("ul.vendor-list li"))
for i in range(length):
    try:
        name = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".headline .name")[i].text
        time = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".badge-info")[i].text.strip()
        rating = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".rating")[i].text
        dealtag = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".multi-tag")[i].text
    except:
        pass
    print(name,time,rating,dealtag)
```

[image]

Comment: Your variables repeat the old values when you get an error. Logically it's doing what your asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because it prints every time even if there's an error, printing whatever was previously stored in your name, time, etc. variables. Try it when you move your print statement within your `try:` block

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('F:/chromedriver')
driver.get("https://www.foodpanda.pk/restaurants/new?lat=24.9414896&lng=67.1676002&vertical=restaurants")


# response = scrapy.Selector(text=driver.page_source)
list = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("ul.vendor-list li")
length = len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("ul.vendor-list li"))
for i in range(length):
    try:
        name = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".headline .name")[i].text
        time = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".badge-info")[i].text.strip()
        rating = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".rating")[i].text
        dealtag = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".multi-tag")[i].text

        print(name,time,rating,dealtag)
    except:
        pass
```